# Flickering lines appear when dragging UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer on a UIView containing a UITableView. In the pan handler I am moving the view containing the tableView.

```
var tableContainerView: UIView
func panGestureHandler(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   let loc = sender.locationInView(self.view)
   let diff = loc.x - startingX
   ...
   tableContainerView.frame.origin.x = diff

}
```

when I move the view it causes a tiny border to flicker around the container view, as well as a flickering on each of the tableView's cells, despite having the tableView's separatorInsetStyle set to .None.

Any idea what might be causing this?? Thanks